# How to run tests with excluded tags in scalatest from maven?

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

I've yet to find an answer for this but in my poms I have:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <tagsToExclude>
            TestTag
        </tagsToExclude>
        ...
```

And I want a way to just run the tests tagged as TestTag. I've tried running

```
mvn test -DtagsToInclude=TestTag
```

but because TestTag is already excluded in the poms, all tests end up being skipped. I've also tried resetting the pom properties:

```
mvn test -DtagsToExclude=None -DtagsToInclude=TestTag
```

But overwriting doesn't work and all of the tests are skipped yet again.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, I just add profile with tagsToExclude property:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <tagsToExclude>TestTag</tagsToExclude>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <tagsToExclude>${tagsToExclude}</tagsToExclude>
```

Now you can run your command and it works:

```
mvn test -DtagsToExclude=None -DtagsToInclude=TestTag
```

Reference: Please see this blog (I'm not an author) https://technicaltesting.wordpress.com/tag/scalatest-maven-plugin/.